Support for furigana
A simple question from a novice at kanji . How can I type furigana text above a kanji, for sake of precision? I have browsed on the Web and I have installed the Google gboard. I cannot find out the setting, if any, to let me type the furigana. Is there an add_on for g board or need I install another keyboard?

I don't think there's native computer support for adding furigana to kanji.

Adding furigana to things is dependent on an individual application or website's settings, it can't be done universally. Are you asking how to do it on Stack Exchange?

To add furigsana on Stack could be a good start.

Furigana is supported in markdown on this SE.
